# nice url with apache and php

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have urls like /story.php?id=31
I want to show it as /31.html
How?

Comment: possible duplicate of [problems getting nice browser url using redirect/rewriterule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553241/problems-getting-nice-browser-url-using-redirect-rewriterule)

Comment: Or here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url+rewrite+php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use Apache's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) engine.

The rule you are looking for would look something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\.html$ story.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 3):

[`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) is the answer. See e.g. [this guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) or [this one](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite).

---

`/31.html` -> `/story.php?id=31` (rendering your links is another - and easier - issue)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^/([0-9]+)\.html$ /story.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using apache and mod_rewrite, a possible sollution could be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\.html /story.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```