# Mask a URL with PHP

Tags: php

I've done some research regarding masking URL's but I'm having some difficulty understanding how it works.  Here is what I am trying to do.

I have a site:

```
www.example.com
```

Sometimes it has directories and get variables that need to be passed.

```
www.example.com/directory/file.php?var=1
```

I'd like to create a custom name for the above are of my site so the user can hit that without remembering the get variables and long directory.

```
www.example.com/customname/file
```

There will also be several different custom names that I will need to produce.

```
www.example.com/customname2/file
www.example.com/customname3/file
etc...
```

Not sure where I should start here but my tests that I have run have all failed giving me an error saying that the "customname" directory does not exist.

What options do I have here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109272/nice-url-with-apache-and-php

Comment: Yes mod_rewrite is what Im looking for.  But now I've run into the problem where I'm trying to just simply ignore a portion of the url.  It happens to be in the middle.  Example:  test.com/removethis/subdir/subfile.php.  I've got it working when I'm in root but it doesn't work within subdirectories.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for a `mod_rewrite`:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're using CodeIgniter, you can do this with their [URI Routing](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cts=1331056522900&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html&ei=ik9WT_7UNM728QOfkKzHCA&usg=AFQjCNHI23CBo4-FEPBd7gdWXz7AKbcZfQ&sig2=62oNBK_UBbpAnF8tlr0H9A) functionality.

Otherwise, use .htaccess and mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

I've solved some of my problems.  But now I have another issue.

For the site:

```
www.example.com/customurl/index.php
RewriteRule customurl/([^/]+)$ /$1
```

This rewrite rule works perfectly and basically ignores the customurl.  However, when I get into subdirectories I get an error saying the page does not exist.  Furthermore, I'd like to set a $_GET variable based on this customurl.  I'm looking for a 1 liner here so that it is easy for me to update.